# Arquivos do Moodle não carregam

Tags: moodle

Boa noite, fiz o upload do Moodle que funcionava no wamp para uma hospedagem e quando tento acessar os materiais dos cursos eles não carregam.
Arquivos em PDF apresentam o seguinte erro `'Error: Bad end offset: 475840' no console.`

Fiz upload de outros arquivos e estes abrem normalmente.